# nx.set_node_attributes not adding the two attributes from either datafram or dict

Tags: python, networkx

I need to create a graph object, with two attributes for each node.

When I create this and add node attributes, I cannot correctly retrieve the values when I call specific nodes.

The code I am using to create the graph object is as follows:

```
nodes = pd.DataFrame(data=N)

E = {'from': ['1','2', '1','5','D','D','D','03','1'],
     'to': ['2','1','5','D','1','1','Z','Z','2'],
     'counts':[22,20,13,15,19,21,20,27,15]}
edges = pd.DataFrame(data=E)

nodes = nodes.set_index('node').T.to_dict('index')


X = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source = 'from', target = 'to', edge_attr = 'counts')
nx.set_node_attributes(X, nodes, 'mode'
```

Using nx.get_node_attributes I am unable to retrieve the attributes applied.

`nx.get_node_attributes(X, '1')`
returns `{}`

I have also tried creating a graph with nx.graph() and subsequently adding the nodes but it ultimately returns the same result

How can I correctly add node attributes to my graph object?

Comment: Does `nx.get_node_attributes(X, 'mode')` return you the attributes?

Comment: @AveragePythonEnjoyer nope - i get the same response, i.e the empty curley brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my question, for those in the future. The following code added the attributes required:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', True, nx.DiGraph())
nx.set_node_attributes(G, all_stations.set_index('node').to_dict('index'))
G.nodes["Z"]
```

A slight change but successful result